# Suggestions on constructing dividers for my chest freezer

Tags: wood, fence, freezer

I have purchased a [14.8 cu ft](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Frigidaire-14-8-Cu-Ft-Chest-Freezer-in-White-FFCL1542AW/315858281) freezer and I want to divide up the space like so, but with taller dividers:

[image: this picture]

The divider shown in the picture is out of stock, and I cannot find a similar product, so I am considering DIY'ing it.

The picture shows five dividers, with the one in the middle perpendicular to the other four. This seems hard, so to keep it simple I will just construct vertical dividers.

My initial thought was to purchase fibreboard from Home Depot and have them cut it to size. The weight of the meats in the fridge would hold the fibreboards in place. But I am concerned that this will impair airflow, and the compartments on the edge may get too hot.

My second idea was to buy or construct a wooden frame and then put chicken wire inside it. Something like this, but much smaller, and without the interior beams:

[image]

I would make 3 of these and stand them upright inside the freezer.

Can you suggest a better way of doing this? Is there a product out there meets my needs?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Why not just use plywood?

Comment: I'm worried that the plywood will impair air circulation, causing the compartments at the edges to get too warm.

Comment: No one does this. Why do you think you need to?  Pork, beef, chicken compartments?  They make special pens to write on freezer paper.

Comment: get 2 egg crates. cut one in half symmetrically. put the open side of the two half against the side walls and the complete crate between those, making 5 pockets:  `|] [] [|` . I would also consider baking racks, wire baskets, or pool baskets from that $1.25 store. Lastly, you don't really need to worry much about air flow, so plastic shoeboxes are great for bags of stuff, and the outside seal helps keep stuff "fresher" longer.

Comment: @SteveWellens because chest freezers are a disaster for organizing things and finding them later. Items tend to work their way to the bottom where they're forgotten for years, and even if you remember and know they're there, it's still a royal pain to dig for them. (Source: me, a 30-year chest freezer owner and hater.) TBH, tall, thin compartments wouldn't be much better, and would leave one wanting if trying to store a pork tenderloin (often 2' long) or a box of 12" frozen pizzas.

Comment: @FreeMan you really need a logbook, or equivalent. A nice thing about my new fridge is that the door is NOT that < *expletive* > "appliance pebble surface," though the sides are. The doors are perfectly smooth and white and work well with dry erase markers as a whiteboard! What's in (that) freezer - look on the door!

Comment: Works well in a store room, @Ecnerwal, probably doesn't go over quite so well in the kitchen. ;)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because appliance engineering is off topic here.

Comment: You're going to dramatically reduce usable space doing this. It's difficult enough fitting a good quantity of stuff in a chest freezer and maintaining access to it. Shrinking independent storage size will compound that challenge. Unless all you store is eight types of frozen food in small containers this will not make life easier.

Comment: @SteveWellens I am mostly storing vacuum-packed hunks of meat. Many kinds - chicken thighs, chicken backs, cuts of beef, cuts of pork, different seafoods etc. Without dividers, everything is in a single pile and it's time consuming to find what I need. I want to minimize the time I keep the lid open.

Comment: @isherwood I am willing to trade space for speed of access. I open the fridge almost every day and minimizing the time the lid is open is important to reduce the load on the freezer and make it last longer.

Comment: A chest freezer lid opening isn't nearly as detrimental as with an upright freezer since the cold air stays in the "bucket" instead of flowing down and out. Whatever you go with, i recommend having matching/uniform containers to allow easy shifting and sliding by having everything interchangeable; that will cut down on "dwell time" and speed random access. Also, since airflow is limited, adding warm food will radiate heat into the surrounding food and slightly thaw it. Therefore, for max storage time, freeze any new food in your regular freezer or outside before placing in the chest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You evidently have some huge misconceptions about "how a deep freezer cools."

Note the complete lack of air vents and fans. Don't have them, don't need them.

You're worried about "stuff at the edges getting too warm" - not going to happen. The coils extracting the heat are **all around the edges, up against the interior metal skin.** Then there's insulation, and usually the hot coils are on the other side against the exterior metal skin - rarely they are somewhere else and might be visible. The interior coils in a chest freezer are always right up against the metal interior skin.

So, the stuff at the edges gets nice and cold.

Dividers - don't need, generally just a waste of precious freezer space, but make from whatever if you want. Airflow is not required, air mostly *does not flow* inside a deep freezer, it just sits and radiates/conducts heat towards the edges until everything is as cold as the edges are. There might be some very minor circulation from convection while cooling down new food. Just don't put anything between the food packages and the inside walls of the freezer, and that will still happen.

If you don't use a water-resistant material, your dividers will be a soggy mess when you have to defrost, and they'll be frozen in place so you won't be able to remove them before defrosting. So use something that tolerates getting wet. Coated wire is standard. They make vinyl coated welded-wire mesh fencing, which could work without a frame of any sort. Some type of plastic (perhaps coroplast - the stuff that looks like cardboard) would be the alternative. It's quite easy to replicate the setup shown in your picture by cutting slots half-way through sheets so they interlock and stand by themselves.

*And if you've never had a deep freezer or a manual-defrost refrigerator, yes, you'll need to defrost "manually" as the specs say. Frost will accumulate on the walls, taking up space and impairing the cooling. I just got done making use of the cold overnight temperatures to put all my food in the car overnight, point a fan into the freezer and melt the accumulated frost, mop up the water that didn't flow out by itself, clean everything and reload the freezer in the morning. It's much easier to do in winter when you can just put the food out in the car, rather than trying to keep it frozen in summertime. ;-)*

Comment: You implicitly assume the coils are on all sides.  Do you know this is the case for the OP's model?

Comment: It is the case for every chest freezer I've ever seen. So it would be exceedingly unlikely not to be the case for that one. I doubt very much that would be mentioned in the specifications.

Comment: Well, the OP would appear to be on the same continent as you, and not me, (from the use of cu ft), so you're more likely to know.  It's not the case with all European models I've used.

Comment: Would be easy to check on a new freezer before you loaded food - turn it on, stick a  pan of hot water in the bottom, close the lid, come back and see where the frost formed, turn it off, defrost/clean, then turn it on to be ready to load food...

Answer (score 0):

A freezer does not rely on air flow. In fact they work best when packed full.

You don't need dividers but you can use anything you want. Use thin cardboard boxes or cheap plastic storage bins cut up the way you like.

Best not to use materials that are good thermal insulators like styrofoam.

Comment: Lower duty cycle, fewer cycles, less internal humidity, faster freezing of new food, more consistent temperature, longer tolerance of power loss, faster recovery after door cycle.   Some of these, admittedly, amount to "more efficient" but if it's possible for a freezer to "work best" (a phrase I used rather loosely), I can't think of too many other criteria.

Comment: Upright freezers, of the type that do rely on airflow (like my previous one, with a fan to drive air over the concealed coils), still work best when really rather full

Answer (score 0):

For a completely different application in work I've used [plastic foamboard](https://amariplastics.com/product/ex-cel-integral-foam/) (NB: many foamboards have paper facing on plastic foam; this is plastic on the faces as well).  While this is insulating, it's also easy to cut with a fine saw, so you can use a holesaw to cut openings in it.  The 5mm I have would be too flexible, but 10mm or 1/2" would be plenty stiff enough